# SQL Server Insert statement to insert long text in a table

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I'm trying to insert long text (> 256 characters) into a table using the standard INSERT ie.

```
INSERT INTO table (description_field)
SELECT 'longtexthere'
```

The column type was first text, then I changed it to nvarchar(max) to test the statement

However, only the first 256 characters are being inserted. Is there another way to insert long text?

Comment: Why don't you use `values`, i.e. `insert into table (description_field) values('longtexthere')`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you sure it's only 256 chars entered? If you're querying to check the result from SSMS, keep in mind that by default only first 256 chars are displayed.

If not this, pls post the table definition and actual INSERT statement. If you're passing value using parameter, check the parameter declaration as well.

Comment: You're right. Only the first 256 characters are shown. It inserts text correctly.